# C++ - trying to point each sub-class to the main class in order to contain all information in a vector

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inventory

Basically, Im writing a small database/inventory system for a game. The item class and its sub-classes (weapon, armor, consumable, etc) are all finally up and working. My vector for inventory is written within a separate inventory class (allows more than one inventory - i.e. enemies can have them too!) and at this point, the inventory is FAR from written - there is still no drop function, etc.

but im taking this one step at a time because its a learning experience.

basically I believe in this case, pointers are the answer. this code seems to work (have not tried it yet)

```
Weapon DebugDagger{ 1, "Debug Dagger", "Debug Dagger given to you by Help", 25 };
Armor DataCloak{ 2, "Data Cloak", "Data Cloak given to you by Help", 10 };
Item *pItem = &DebugDagger;
Weapon *pWeapon = &DebugDagger;
InventoryManager PlayerInv;
PlayerInv.pickupItem(pWeapon);`
```

in this case, `pickupItem(Item*)` is taking a static Item type - which is the base class for my function, where the weapon being added to the inventory is a sub-class (`class Weapon : public Item{}`)

the way this is written seems to hack together a solution, but it would be MUCH easier if I could just write the pointer into the class functions themselves so that EACH item created in a sub-class automatically will create a pointer of itself to the base class so I can add it into the inventory subsystem. Is there a way to do this from Within the class? so that EACH member gets a pointer created automatically upon class creation? When I try to use the name variable in the constructor to do this, it does not work, as it seems I have to create the member BEFORE making a pointer, so I dont see how to do it at the same time anticipating a new member being created.

I mean, I'm all for other more effective ideas than a std::vector inventory; for an inventory - I think some function that actually can simply accept the members of any class and record them would be FAR more effective in the long run, but I do not believe this is possible - I think that creating pointers to Item from the sub-classes  would still be necessary - seeing as, really, its all items, with each sub function having a single extra specifier ONLY being used for its own function, weapon has attack, consumable has restoration, etc -and its ALL integers, so really those are the same as each other almost, but for function reasons, like equipping, using, classifying, they each get a separate type I suppose I couldve made a SpecialItem subclass to cover it all, but that would be very ambiguous, and leave little room for innovation should a specific type need modification later.

I just dont see it if there is an alternative. if there is direct me and I will read voraciously until I find understanding of it.

Comment: You need to be careful about the term `sub-class`, as opposed to `sub-object`.  A member of an object is a `sub-object`.  A `sub-class` is a class that inherits from another class.  It helps to think of `class` as a *type* of object.  Instances of a class are not "the class".  This is important for two reasons: first, communication, and second, because distinguishing between types and values of that type is an important pattern.

Comment: I see no need for *either* pointer in this code. `&DebugDagger` passed as the parameter to `pickupItem` should work correctly if indeed the sole parameter to said-function is `Item*` *and* `Weapon` is indeed a derivative of `Item`. If you indeed have items that are so truly different, perhaps a separate `Armor` and `Weapon` container may be more appropriate for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i got the point, but a pointer to the subclass (Weapon) *is already* a pointer to the base class (Item).

So you can store all your items (Weapon : Item, Arnmor : Item, ...) in your

```
std::vector<Item*> Inventory
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to work this way, because by default NO pointer is being created, in this instance I Had to write one on the fly after creating the Item in order for it to push_back.

otherwise it tells me class Weapon cannot be converted to Item * and wont compile.

so it seems to me that I CAN"T store them into the vector -- for that to work it would have to be

```
std::vector<Weapon*> Inventory
```

basically I need the functionality of

```
std::vector<Weapon*> Inventory
std::vector<Armor*> Inventory2
std::vector<Consumable*> Inventory3
std::vector<Item*> Inventory4
```

except I need it in ONE single inventory class...

my problem is right now I ONLY have
std::vector,
and NO other class type is ALLOWED to be inserted into this slot, because I have to either convert the type manually (since memory can't do it on its own, the special characteristics have to be dropped), or create a pointer to Item* so that when I insert the POINTER  like this:

`Inventory.push_back(POINTER);`

it will BELIEVE the weapon is an Item, and go ahead with the operation.

otherwise

```
Inventory.push_back(WEAPON), etc do not work... only Inventory.push_back(Item*)
```

I dont know if this has been any more clear, but it should make it understandable why I need the pointer. Since I cannot cast a Weapon or even a Weapon * as an Item, I have to create a pointer to Item somewhere in the class function, so that way I have some variable I could automatically pop into the push_back function INSTEAD of the member of the class itself - I sort of have to cloak a weapon or potion as a basic item in order to get it to fit into the vector, because it only accepts basic items as is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, either way - the code ended up being NONFUNCTIONAL IN ENTIRETY.

regardless of this, I need a way to create a database of all members of each type of class.

I need the functionality of a vector, that will work with any type -- or a method to get a vector to accept any type.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on this method, because it just will not work to have one vector alone.

now Im working on a 3 vector class of obtained item names, quantities, and IDs.

it seems a bit** to figure out how to associate the 3 and also scan through them in unison to make data make sense (I.e. see if item name x, id 32 is in inventory, if it is, allow user to examine such item for details).

this is my first big project really. its a doozy for me.